# What does the underscore mean in this case?

Tags: syntax, swift2

my code before the migation to Swift 2.0:

```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "RhymeFavoriten") {
        // pass data to next view
        let dest = segue.destinationViewController as! FavoritenViewController
        let source = segue.sourceViewController as! RhymeViewController // !!!!!!
        dest.favoritenType = 1
        dest.delegate = self
    }
}
```

the migration told me to change it to

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "RhymeFavoriten") {
        // pass data to next view
        let dest = segue.destinationViewController as! FavoritenViewController
        _ = segue.sourceViewController as! RhymeViewController // !!!!!!!!!!
        dest.favoritenType = 1
        dest.delegate = self
    }
```

or

```
    func textSelected(selectedText:String, selectedType:Int) {
        var fullTextArr = text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        var myArray = [String]()  // !!!!!!
```

to

```
    func textSelected(selectedText:String, selectedType:Int) {
        var fullTextArr = text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        _ = [String]()    // !!!!!!!!!
```

I can´t see, what is **_ =** standing for :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_` is a placeholder. It means that the values assigned to `_` are ignored.

Xcode's migration tool made this changes because it has detected that you didn't use `source` or `myArray` anywhere, thus replaced these variables by the placeholder.

Now instead of being assigned to a variable, the returning result of `segue.sourceViewController as! RhymeViewController` and the returning  result of `[String]()` are ignored.

The returning result is ignored but the expression is still evaluated at runtime: if it has side effects, these effects will occur.

So if you actually don't need these instructions you should get rid of them entirely.

Comment: are they ignored or is it just a compiler optimization, as there is no need to store a reference to a variable that isnt used?

Comment: They are computed (evaluated) but the returning result (if any) is not assigned in memory, it is voided.

Comment: evaluated at compile time rather than runtime

Comment: No, they are evaluated at runtime. But the result is ignored (not assigned to a variable). If these functions have side effects, these effects will occur; it's just that if they return something, this thing will be ignored.

Comment: @Eric D. many thanks! That makes sense and i understand it ;-)