# Immutable value X is never used consider replacing with '_' error in Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm following the Stanford Swift Course on Youtube. In the first lesson you start by making an layout for a calculator. I've linked the buttons from the calculator to my code and this generated the following piece:

```
    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle

    print(_)
}
```

I keep getting the warning "Immutable value X is never used consider replacing with '_' error in Swift 2" for the constant "digit". I just don't get my head around what I am doing wrong here. I mean, it still does run ofcourse but it's say I dont need to use this constant? I mean, lets for example say I want to print this constant, than I'm using it so I can't replace it with _. Who can clarify this for me? It also seems that the professor in the Stanford course didnt have any problems with it so it should be a recent fix in Xcode. I'm btw using the most recent version of Xcode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the underscore mean in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656095/what-does-the-underscore-mean-in-this-case)

Answer (score 5):

It just means that you declare digit constant:

```
let digit = sender.currentTitle
```

but you don't use it later at all.
Compiler suggest you to replace digit with _:

```
let _ = sender.currentTitle
```

which is special syntax which tells compiler don't create any variable/constant for this.

If you will use digit later in code the warning diseapeare:

```
let digit = sender.currentTitle
print("\(digit)")
```

I haven't seen this video but I believe this constant will be used later so you can simple ignore the warning.