# Unused variables and '_'

Tags: swift

I am learning swift using [learnxinyminutes.com](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/swift/)

I'm having a hard time understanding a component of on of the examples on the site (below), namely the use of underscore in the `let` statements instead of variable names.

```
// Variadic Args
func setup(numbers: Int...) {
    let _ = numbers[0]
    let _ = numbers.count
}
```

I understand that swift wants you to use underscore if you never declare the variable, but 1) why would you want to declare variables you never use? And 2) is there a way to get those values out if you used `_`. And, 3) if so, how?

Comment: As far as I can see it's just trying to demonstrate that `numbers` is an array (you can index it, it has a `.count`) without actually using those values (hence throwing them away with `_`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the underscore mean in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656095/what-does-the-underscore-mean-in-this-case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) why would you want to declare variables you never use?

Generally you don't! There are some cases though where you might want to, such as the example Danny Buonocore gave. Another example might be this: say you want to check that a variable is non-nil before you do something, though you do not need that variable for the subsequent code. (A guard statement is probably more useful in these situations).

```
if let _ = titleString {
// Do something that doesn't use titleString, but where it being non-nil means this operation is valid
}
```

Another example is with Swift functions. Names for a second, third, etc. parameter must be identified whenever calling a function. For example:

```
func externalizedParameters(first: Int?, second: Int?) {
...
}
```

Which is called using `externalizedParameters(5, second: 6)`.

But if you are doing something trivial, and the function name already makes it clear what the two parameters are, such as with a swap operation, you might not want to force the caller to explicitly state the name of the second parameter. In that case, you can use '_' because you don't care about the name of that externalized parameter:

```
func swap(first: Int?, _ second: Int?) {
    ...
}
```

This can then be called as `swap(5, 6)` as opposed to `swap(5, second: 6)`.

2) is there a way to get those values out if you used _. & 3) if so, how?

No. You need to name the variable if you want to use the value.

Comment: The accepted answer in this question also provides further great insight. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656095/what-does-the-underscore-mean-in-this-case. It's not directly a duplicate because I had multiple questions regarding the underscore, but future users should reference both.

Answer (score 1):

One example would be a loop where you don't necessarily need the index.

```
for _ in 0..<10 {

}
```

In swift you can also externalize the names of the parameters.  This allows the caller to pass by name, rather than order:

```
func myFunction(param1:String, param2:String) {

}

myFunction(param2: "second value", param1: "first value");
```

If you don't want to externalize the name of a parameter, you can include an underscore before it, like so:

```
func myFunction(param1:String, _ param2:String) {

}
```

In this case, you must pass the value to set param2 to as the second argument, and you cannot use the naming scheme seen in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the value inside of a variable, declare it with a name and not `_`. The underscore says, I know this call returns a value but we're not going to use it, so it doesn't need a name. Swift emits warnings for unused function call results, so this is a way to suppress that warning.